# HTML image not positioning in Email

Tags: html, css, image, email, positioning

I am playing with email footers nowadays and when I create a template in CodePen, it looks fine there. But when sending it in an actual email, it is not positioning the image correctly, and also other CSS selectors are removed from the code.

This is the code:

```html
<div text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonumes voluptatum mel ea, cu case ceteros cum. Novum commodo malorum vix ut. Dolores consequuntur in ius, sale electram dissentiunt quo te. Cu duo omnes invidunt, eos eu mucius fabellas. Stet facilis ius te, quando voluptatibus
  eos in. Ad vix mundi alterum, integre urbanitas intellegam vix in.<br>
  <br>
  <img style="min-width:640px;display:block;margin:0;padding:0" class="m_1407183270023890199mobileOff" height="1" width="640">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#F6F6F6" width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center" width="100%">

          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" height="250" width="640" border="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/JAbXR1Vkz0jOIyy2fakaw4tgm7dpLH4RxhPcLi6NFo2q0avwsD5UAq1CjxS4oYCItQgp59V3xvh98KEEWlZLjLjFKGo=s0-d-e1-ft#http://content.smohai.com/email/imageteszt.png" valign="center" align="left" height="200"
                    width="145" class="CToWUd"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="m_1407183270023890199name" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="80px" width="600px"> LOGO </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="m_1407183270023890199name" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="40px" width="600px"> Tamas Smohai </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="m_1407183270023890199designation" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30px" width="600px"> Director </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#4a4a4a" height="30px" width="600px">
                  <table class="m_1407183270023890199links" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table class="m_1407183270023890199link" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" border="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="m_1407183270023890199link1">
                                  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=hu&amp;q=https://www.facebook.com/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1507498301190000&amp;usg=AFQjCNGlfrj0LoC5g9LZGFffv2BsCrjaig"><img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/lqmSxKdWYmc30Ry2EBqcFG-dedYpuVaY1xBn0QrkY70jv724sm1X_bYeCGU_gdj8zHqFR0rgiIVspDVQsck0INJPCXtToAIUc5bTCZwKiA=s0-d-e1-ft#http://content.smohai.com/sample/Type011/facebookicon.png"
                                      alt=" " height="12" width="7" class="CToWUd"></a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="m_1407183270023890199link2">
                                  <a href="http://www.skype.com/en/" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=hu&amp;q=http://www.skype.com/en/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1507498301190000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHJILVr-zIRsq1TcT2g7PI8ME8Zag"><img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/ErVHPNyBh8iNJQIWTagISNt60af8wLQ47tT-Q3kecWmu7gTzNV-LMu9Pri7klaXpCXt3W6EKpIC6Iap479bmAf_7g1bc87hMFBawOg=s0-d-e1-ft#http://content.smohai.com/sample/Type011/skypeicon.png"
                                      alt=" " height="12" width="12" class="CToWUd"></a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="m_1407183270023890199link3">
                                  <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=hu&amp;q=https://twitter.com/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1507498301190000&amp;usg=AFQjCNEzHhrZ3eUHvnDuquuK4syrwwrwLw"><img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/ENpU-chMPdg9_0gGBgU2wrtizP7Q_z3hTJsj9I7_nb-w8O9wHi_HSC9zYRmpaapy7L5LTZvA_AisgOT8OOh8Z1UHbrYStaFFNbevWEwr=s0-d-e1-ft#http://content.smohai.com/sample/Type011/twittericon.png"
                                      alt=" " height="9" width="12" class="CToWUd"></a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="m_1407183270023890199link4">
                                  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=hu&amp;q=https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1507498301190000&amp;usg=AFQjCNETGi2Ysdgwp9zaWep5YqTVpcx3dw"><img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/r-Z1eRyS9qlfdov25U2gflMYDC60iXEcxsiAG-n21ugZYvh_c6DqjOrP7kcKJBsVRjUaQWMNTQCkgaQe3VhHbIMjQ9sUUxE-Lj5ghVYK9Q=s0-d-e1-ft#http://content.smohai.com/sample/Type011/linkedinicon.png"
                                      alt=" " height="11" width="10" class="CToWUd"></a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff6458" height="70px" width="600px">
                  <table class="m_1407183270023890199icons" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="m_1407183270023890199icon1"> <img src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/FUCTXNf3Zvc4XO-IEtdpEzLZdGHDBGyR04NOTk4hKCboSZ_ItGSqKuXi73a4vLsFmVYcAY9ZOsTzu32Vgu_ZXUrsnMOaiCZQH6QYaDI=s0-d-e1-ft#http://content.smohai.com/sample/Type011/mobileicon.png"
                                    alt=" " height="12" width="8" class="CToWUd"> </td>
                                <td class="m_1407183270023890199icontext2"><a href="tel:+44%207936%20434744" value="+447936434744" target="_blank">+44(0)7936434744</a></td>
                                <td class="m_1407183270023890199devider2">| </td>
                                <td class="m_1407183270023890199icon2"> <img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/YQIw17P66kIKRUmccVn99_KDkm4ArL6P7THZm4Z4nr4L-RYi4l8XfMbt3P1XC5sB0NdRX9iiqzLkGJN77rqlyw3jivYvNfHTMQ90UAgP=s0-d-e1-ft#http://content.smohai.com/sample/Type011/messageicon.png"
                                    alt=" " height="11" width="15" class="CToWUd"></td>
                                <td class="m_1407183270023890199icontext3"><a class="m_1407183270023890199moz-txt-link-abbreviated" href="mailto:info@stayalivelonger.co.uk" target="_blank">info@stayalivelonger.co.uk</a></td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="m_1407183270023890199address_bg">
                        <td>
                          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="m_1407183270023890199address"> Church Road, Rory Reay Avenue, Los Angeles. </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="yj6qo"></div>
  <div class="adL">

  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it should be and how it is displayed in an Email:

[image: Mail image positioning problem]

My question would be the reason behind this, and also how to get around this behavior.

Comment: Mail clients are notoriously irritating.  Check out campaignmonitor.com/css/ and Litmus for some help on making email templates.

Comment: What CSS rules have you declared to position the `img` in that manner? Chances are these are some of the rules being removed, or they may not be supported by most email clients. General rule of thumb when it comes to html parsing in email clients: stick to basics(like it's the 90s all over again), use tables for structuring, keep it simple (no fancy stuff), use inline-styles.

Answer (score 0):

You posted your code, but not your classes. I think I detect positioning and that really doesn't work across the board with email development. I know it looks like front-end development, but it has different rules.

The following code will give you a two color background and an image. It doesn't work with Outlook or Yahoo!, it needs some fine-tuning to work correctly in mobile, but it works in most email clients like IOS, Apple Mail and Gmail.

This is the code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/kdxwg8ct/

Good luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table height="600" width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%,black 50%,#000000 50%,red 50%,red 100%); border: 4px solid #000000;">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <img src="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg" border="8" style="border: 8px solid #ffffff; Margin-left: 40px;" vspace="60"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```